# Why is my script only working for the last line of my text file?

Tags: python

I'm using Python 2 and I'm reading a file with 400 ish domain names(separated by new lines) into my script, testing if they match the expression '*.in' and if they do, saving them to a list and writing the list to a new .txt.  However, the script only picks up the last .in domain in the file and there are several more.  Any ideas?

```
    #!/usr/bin/python

from fnmatch import fnmatch

newDomains = []


with open ('fishDomains.txt', 'r+') as f:
    for line in f:
        print line
        if fnmatch(line, '*.in') is True:
            print line
            newDomains.append(line)

with open('newFishDomains.txt', 'r+') as c:
    for item in newDomains:
        #print item
        c.write(item)
        c.write("\n")
```

Comment: Is the print showing you the other .in files?

Comment: `fnmatch` looks for a single match. Try this: `if '.in' in line:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After my test, I think that should be the `End of Line` symbol cause the problem. In my environment (win7), I open a test file showed as following (to be more specific, I also show the EoL symbol)

```
testline1.in\r\n
ttline2.in\r\n
line3.in
```

applying your code to this file, it only shows ['line3.in']. Therefore I suggest you to use `strip()`, which cut the end of line symbol (both **LF** or **CRLF**) and remove the leading trailing space.

My modified code is as below:

```
with open ('fishDomains.txt', 'r+') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()   # <====================
        print line
        if fnmatch(line, '*.in') is True:
            print line
            newDomains.append(line)
```

one thing should be noted that the **old** macOS system used **CR** as EoL, which kind of EoL would fail with `strip`, but that's more than 10 years ago, should have no problem now.

Answer (score 1):

`for line in f` where `f` is an opened file returns entire lines, including the terminating newline.

You want to strip the line, and probably not use `fnmatch` for something which built-in string functions can do.

```
with open ('fishDomains.txt', 'r+') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip('\r\n')
        if line.endswith('.in'):
            print line
            newDomains.append(line)
```

As an aside, you should usually take care that *all* the lines in your text files have a proper line ending character.

As another aside, the list variable is slightly clumsy, and not very scalable.  For large files in particular, it makes sense to write out what you found as soon as possible, instead of collect all the data in memory.

```
with open('newFishDomains.txt', 'r+') as c:
    with open ('fishDomains.txt', 'r+') as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.rstrip('\r\n')
            if line.endswith('.in'):
                print line
                c.write(line + '\n')
```

Finally, in shell, this is obviously a one-liner:

```
grep '\.in$' fishDomains.txt >newFishDomains.txt
```

Comment: If I may ask: wouldn't reading and writing at the same time be a) major performance killer because b) the harddrive would constantly jump between two files? That wouldn't be an issue with 10MB input and just a few matches. But imagine 10MB with every line matching. I assume that would take quite a while because of the mechanics of the harddrive, while having everything in memory and writing it in one big block would run pretty fast. And if memory is limited, write the content in chunks. Line by line at least seems not all that efficient to me (currently).

Comment: Good question really.  OS buffering mitigates this somewhat, but yes, keeping everything in memory and then writing it all out at once is typically faster in the optimal case.  The proposed change trades speed for robustness in the less optimal case when keeping everything in memory becomes a bottleneck. If you only ever anticipate small inputs, it doesn't really matter anyway. But when building tools, you usually want them to scale gracefully -- if you have a bunch of these chained together, you could easily end up with dozens of copies of your data in memory if your tools behave this way.